# How to download old package on Alpine Linux

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

Goal: download (not install) old versions of Alpine packages, ultimately for use in a container.

For Debian, there's https://snapshot.debian.org/

I couldn't find anything equivalent for Alpine.

Is there an official source for old versions of Alpine Linux packages?

And I wasn't able to get the package I needed following this question on a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939670/install-older-package-version-in-alpine

EDIT: specifically looking for `tesseract-ocr` 3.04, in a way that I can install with `apk`

Comment: Does the [Alpine web GUI for packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages) have what you are looking for?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Yes! But: none of the links seems to result in a download.  How do I actually get something I can install with `apk` from there?  I'm trying to get `tesseract-ocr` 3.04, which I found here:  https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/community/x86_64/tesseract-ocr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [web GUI for Alpine packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages) which can help you locate which Alpine distributions contained which versions of software.

Once you know the version of Alpine your package can be found in, you can search the [browsable package repositories](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/) for the package you wish to download.

For example, the `x86_64` package of `tesseract-ocr` version 3.04 can be found in the `community` repository of Alpine v3.6 at: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/tesseract-ocr-3.04.01-r1.apk